# The state variable is never a parameter of a function, right? (How to Design Programs)

Tags: variables, functional-programming, global, state

In [Chapter 36.4 of HTDP(How to Design Programs)](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-45.html#node_sec_36.4),

I found this warning:

***Warning: The state variable is never a parameter of a function.***

But as far as I've heard before, in functional programming, functions will be corrupted if they refer state variables. They will not be pure functions anymore. They will be hard to test, do unpredictable works, cannot be memoized ... etc. The state variables also should be passed by as parameters, not just referred as some global constants.

So I wonder

- is HTDP is arguing something wrong,
- in some of functional programming practices, global state variables are allowed? or
- I have wrong idea?

Thanks in advance.

*Disclaimer: I like&respect this book very much and learned a lot. Actually I would like to spread good words about this book to my friends(if any). So don't get it wrong.*

Comment: Conceptual software development questions (i.e. *specific* questions about code) are better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Thank you for noting this. I will try that site from now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything incompatible with what you've heard about functional programming and what is written in the chapter you linked.  However, you're conflating two concepts here:  the presence of mutable state in functional programs (a *purity* issue) vs. the order in which things are evaluated, and the restrictions on the syntax you have available to write things down.

Consider:  if you're using an eager evaluation strategy, then passing a "state variable" of the kind they describe in that chapter would have the effect of dereferencing it, and you would get the *value* of the variable as the function argument.  Similarly, if the variable was bound as a parameter to the function, you would get a *different* bit of memory at every call.  There are many different options here.  The fact that some languages permit you to pass references around as values is not universal.

So they are really just describing global variables (or variables that are accessed from some parent scope), which by their very nature need not be passed to functions as parameters.  If the specific language permits pass-by-reference, this might not be such a clear distinction.

Comment: I've used too much Clojure so didn't think the issue of copy of values. Thanks!